# How to make a 'one OF many relationships' relationship in MySQL/Laravel

Tags: php, mysql, database, laravel, relationship

Before I get into the question, I am not asking about a one to many relationship.

I have a table called `enrollments`, an enrollment can either be a `lecture`, `test`, or `aptitude`. The table `enrollments` has a one to many relationship with the `lectures` table, the `tests` table and the `aptitudes` table.

My question is: how can I make it so an enrollment is allowed to be linked to only one of these three tables? Currently the database allows the enrollment to be both a lecture and a test for example, which shouldn't be possible.

Visual representation of the problem:
[image]

I googled for a good few hours but could not find anyone with a similar problem, please help. Thanks in advance.

Comment: This kind of problem can be symptomatic of flawed schema design

Comment: If enrollment is only one among the three, then the other 2 relationships will be empty and you do not have to worry about them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you are using laravel, this seems like a good time to try using the many-to-one [polymorphic relationship](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/eloquent-relationships#polymorphic-relationships).

So the idea will be that your `enrollments` table will have a relationship called `enrollable` which can point to either of the 3 tables. Note: the name `enrollable` is just following laravel's example naming convention.

To implement this relationship you need to first create the migration, where you can use the convenient [morphs](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/migrations#creating-columns) method like so

```
// This will make 2 columns called 'enrollable_type' (VARCHAR) and 'enrollable_id' (UNSIGNED BIGINT)

Schema::table('enrollments', function (Blueprint $table) {
    ...
    $table->morphs('enrollable'); 
});
```

And then you just have to setup the relationship in your models

```
// In the Enrollment model you define the enrollable relationship which will be either of 3 model

public function enrollable()
{
     return $this->morphTo('enrollable','enrollable_type','enrollable_id');
}

// in your 3 models you can specify the opposite relationship to refer back to the enrollment

public function enrollments()
{
     return $this->morphMany('App\Enrollment', 'enrollable', 'enrollable_type', 'enrollable_id');
}
```

When this is setup properly you can use this new relationship like the standard one-to-many relationship. such as `$lecture->enrollments` to get all enrollments to a lecture.

Answer (score 0):

Since enrollment is only one among the three, the other 2 relationships will be empty and you do not have to worry about them.

Let's say a student is enrolling for a lecture then the table row will have `NULL` value for test_id and aptitude_id and thus those will be empty relationships.